# OpenGL showing more/less of the world through resize

Tags: opengl, viewport

So a lot of questions online about resizing have been about maintaining the right ratios and avoid stretching etc. From what I understand, this would be done by setting the new ratio with `gluOrtho2D`.

However, I wasn't sure exactly how to go about showing MORE and LESS of the world upon resize. E.g. you have a plane that could travel from 0 to 100 along the x axis. Upon resizing, it should now (still same size) travel from 0 to 200.

EDIT: so what I mean is, I want everything in my game to stay the same size as before, but the "sky" if you will, should be bigger upon the resize, and my plane should be able to fly into that sky (since currently I have code that limits it to within the screen).

Similarly, if my screen is smaller, then the plane should no longer be able to fly to the section of the 'sky' that no longer exists

Initially, I'm setting up my program using the following lines, where everything about the game is stored in 'game', and XSize, YSize returns the size of the screen.

```
void init(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0); /* set background color to a dark blue */
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); /* set drawing color to white */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, game.getXSize()*game.getAspect(), 0, game.getYSize() / game.getAspect()); /* defines world window */
}    

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    game = GameManager(GAMENAME, 1000, 750, 60);

    /*SETUP*/
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(game.getXSize(), game.getYSize());
    glutCreateWindow(GAMENAME);
    /*Other GLUT main function lines here */
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
}
```

When I try to set up the gluOrtho2D in resize, however, the program sets up the background and stops drawing anything at all.

```
void resize(int w, int h){
    game.setScreenSize(w,h);
    glViewport(0,0,width,height) 
    const GLfloat aspectRatio = (GLfloat)game.getXSize() / (GLfloat)game.getYSize();
    gluOrtho2D(0, game.getXSize()*game.getAspect(), 0, game.getYSize() / game.getAspect());
}
```

I have, of course, managed to just use  glViewport(0,0,w,h) by itself, but that's pretty much the same as not doing anything at all (the graphics just stretch, and functions I'm using to move objects to the mouse position no longer work properly), since glViewport is called by default if I don't create a Reshape function.

Comment: I'm unsure what you specifically mean. You mention showing more or less, but then also mention showing the same where the viewport is scaled. Which one is it? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I'll update my question to be more clear, sorry

Comment: So if I understand you correctly. You want the in-game distance to change, based on the size of the viewport. Thus not just scaling the viewport to correctly fit the screen? It sounds a bit odd. What is the end goal?

Comment: I'm just trying to draw a scene that may not be entirely visible in the initial window set up. When I resize the window, I'd like to be able to see more (or less) of that scene, without stretching or resizing the scene

Answer (score 0):

The general way world coordinates get mapped to screen in OpenGL is:

> world coordinates --> clip space coordinates --> device coordinates

The "world coordinates" are just whatever you feed to OpenGL as vertex data.  They can be whatever you want, there are no rules.

The vertex shader (or matrix stack, if you are time traveling to the 1990s) is what transforms world coordinates to clip space coordinates.

The clip space coordinates go from –1…+1.  So (–1,–1) is the lower-left corner of the window, (–1,+1) is the top left, (+1,+1) is the top right, etc.  This is the same no matter what size your window is.  So if your window gets larger, the picture will *also* get larger, unless you scale down the clip space coordinates at the same time.

So if you want to keep the same world coordinates and keep the same size in pixels, you have to change the way world coordinates are transformed to clip space.  In general, this means that if your window gets twice as big, your clip space coordinates should get half as big, in order to keep everything the same size.

Typically, to achieve this, you'll end up multiplying in a matrix that looks something like this:

```
int windowWidth = ..., windowHeight = ...;
double matrix[2][2] = {
    { 1.0 / windowWidth,                0.0 },
    {               0.0, 1.0 / windowHeight },
};
```

That's if you're using a 2D matrix.  Change this appropriately if you are using `glOrtho` or for your particular vertex shader.  Or just read the manual for `glOrtho`.

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
gluOrtho2D(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Which would be the same as:

```
glOrtho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Then I'm assuming your problem is that [when you scale a scene like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxqju.png), then it ends up looking like this:

[image]

As you say this can be fixed by taking the aspect ratio into account. Given the `width` and `height` of your screen. Then you can calculate the aspect ratio and set the proper orthographic projection:

```
const GLfloat aspectRatio = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;

gluOrtho2D(-aspectRatio, aspectRatio, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

This now results in everything scaling in relation to the aspect ratio, and subsequently allowing you to *see more*.

[image]

Since the above is actually a sphere in 3D, setting the `near` and `far` values is also needed:

```
glOrtho(-aspectRatio, aspectRatio, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the program goes from some negative value to an equally large positive value?
I'm just asking because in my case, my program goes from 0 to some value x, 0 to some value y by default.
When I try using gluOrtho2D, however, the game no longer draws anything at all. (I'm passing it values (0, width, 0, height)